# Different line styles on AChartEngine

Tags: achartengine

Is it possible to have different width or styles (dashed) for each chart line in one XYMultipleSeriesRenderer? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` has several `XYSeriesRenderer`, one for each series of data. The changes that are applied to an `XYSeriesRenderer` are visible on that line only. For instance, the line width can be applied per line.